# MySqlException occured : Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here's my code.

```
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Try
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO maleintventoty(item_brad,item_size,item_quantity,item_description) VALUES(@item_brad,@item_size,@item_description,@item_quantity)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_brand", brandtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_size", sizetxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_description", descriptiontxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_quantity", quantitytxt.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Done")
        brandtxt.Clear()
        descriptiontxt.Clear()
        quantitytxt.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
       Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO maleintventoty(item_brad,item_size,item_quantity,item_description) VALUES(@item_brad,@item_size,@item_description,@item_quantity)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_brand", brandtxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_size", sizetxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_description", descriptiontxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_quantity", quantitytxt.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Done")
        brandtxt.Clear()
        descriptiontxt.Clear()
        quantitytxt.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: plz format your code and add badly needed details.  See [Ask]

Comment: ok tnx. new to stackoverflow

Comment: cant format my question-.-

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you just copy paste your code? if yes then the error is probably because of a typo.

In your query you have "@item_brad", when you're setting its value you have "@item_brand".

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your parameters value name. that is not correctly matched.
In your query you have "@item_brad", when you're setting its value you have "@item_brand".